# How to set dynamically domain for a List

Tags: prolog

for example, i create list following

```
length(List,5),
List :: 1..5,
```

I want to set second element of list, it looks like 
`List[1] :: 1..2`     %List, from 0 to 4

I don't know how to realize it ?

thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, using `in` operator in Swi-prolog, I can do like this:

```
init_static(List) :- length(List, 5), List in 1..5, List = [_,Y|_], Y in 1..2.
```

if I know beforehand that I need specific constraints for the second element.

To generalize for any index:

```
init_dynamic(I, List) :- length(List, 5), List in 1..5, length(L1, I), Y in 1..2, append(L1, [Y|_], List).
```

So a query for the second element is:

```
init_dynamic(1, [1,2,4,3,5]).
true.
```

I assume that you can do similar things with `::` operator in other Prolog variants.